# Linked list destructor C++

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, aggregate, destructor

I'm learning to implement Stack using linked list. This is the node class:

```
class StudentInfo {
    public:
        string id, name, course;
        double GPA;
        StudentInfo *next;
};
```

This is the Stack class:

```
class StackLinkedList {
    public:
        StudentInfo* top; //pointer to point to the top node
        int size; //variable to keep the size of the stack

    //constructor
    StackLinkedList() {
        this->size = 0;
        this->top = NULL;
    }

    //destructor
    ~StackLinkedList() {
        StudentInfo *current = top;
        while (top) {
            current = current->next;
            delete top;
            top = current;
        }
    }

    //to add item into stack - push on top
    void push(StudentInfo *newStudent) {
        if (!top) {
            top = newStudent;
            return;
        }

        newStudent->next = top;
        top = newStudent;
        size++;
    }

void main() {
    StudentInfo s1("phi", "123", "computer science", 4.0);
    StudentInfo s2("abc", "123", "software engineer", 4.0);
    StudentInfo s3("zxc", "123", "business management", 4.0);

    StackLinkedList list;
    StudentInfo *ptr;
    ptr = &s1;
    list.push(ptr);
    ptr = &s2;
    list.push(ptr);
    ptr = &s3;
    list.push(ptr);

};
```

When I try to run unit test on push() and printAll(), everything is okay. However, after destructor() has been called, and error is showed up Debug Assertion Failed … is_block_type_valid(header-> _block_use). And the debugger triggered a breakpoint at `delete top;`

```
//destructor
~StackLinkedList() {
    StudentInfo *current = top;
    while (top) {
        current = current->next;
        delete top; //here
        top = current;
    }
}
```

If I put `top = NULL;` before `delete top;`, the error is gone. So, I have a little bit of confusion about the `top = NULL;` statement.
Edit: Constructor for NodeType

```
 StudentInfo(string id, string name, string course, double gpa) {
        this->id = id; this->name = name; this->course = course; this->GPA = gpa; this->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Recommended read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: First thing first, try running valgrind and check if there are any memory leaks.

Comment: 1) Don't use raw `new`/`delete`. Use smart pointers (or just plain containers of objects). 2) Don't use `NULL`. Use `nullptr`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl is it valid if I try to return nullptr for pointer return type?

Comment: @Phi Truong you *can* return `nullptr`, sure. Whether or not that's what you *want* and what your callers *expect* is a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You invoked Undefined Behavior by attempting to `delete` objects of *automatic storage duration*.

```
int main() {
    StudentInfo s1("phi", "123", "computer science", 4.0);
    StudentInfo s2("abc", "123", "software engineer", 4.0);
    StudentInfo s3("zxc", "123", "business management", 4.0);

    StackLinkedList list;
    StudentInfo *ptr;
    ptr = &s1;
    list.push(ptr);
    ptr = &s2;
    list.push(ptr);
    ptr = &s3;
    list.push(ptr);

};
```

As you can see, `s1`, `s2`, `s3` are objects of *automatic storage duration* (aka, the compiler automatically invokes their destructors at the end of their lifetime).

Yet you pass their addresses to `list`, whose destructor `deletes` all pointers within its linked-list-detail, upon destruction.... Never call `delete` on a pointer to an object that wasn't created using `new`.

---

Some additional notes:

- `void main()` is illegal in C++. Are you using an older compiler? ..
- Every object should manage its resource. A `std::forward_list` for example manages the allocation of its nodes internally using allocators. I suggest you redesign `StackLinkedList` to manage its nodes internally, so that clients will never bother about lifetimes.
- You should read up on the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and [The Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)
- There are some other bugs in your code, I've not touched.

Comment: One more question, I don't really understand how `top = NULL` can solved this problem?

Comment: after your `top = NULL`, the following `delete top` become a "delete NULL`, which is basically a no op (does not call any dtor, does not free any memory)

Comment: @PhiTruong, How you can perform unit tests internally would be beyond the scope of answers here. However, you would of cause have lots of test cases for `StackLinkedList` as a *Unit*. ...And as to your second comment, Gian Paolo has explained...

Answer (score 1):

For starters you sis not initialize the data member `next` of objects of the type `StudentInfo`.

So all the code that relies on that the last node in the list is equal to `nullptr` will invoke undefined behavior.

Also you may not use the operator delete for objects that were not created with operator new.

So instead of the statements

```
StudentInfo s1("phi", "123", "computer science", 4.0);
StudentInfo s2("abc", "123", "software engineer", 4.0);
StudentInfo s3("zxc", "123", "business management", 4.0);
```

you should at least write (I assume that `StudentInfo` is an aggregate. If the class has a constructor then declare it like

```
StudentInfo( const string &id, 
             const string &name, 
             const string &course, 
             double gpa, 
             StudentInfo *next = nullptr ) 
{
        this->id = id; this->name = name; this->course = course; this->GPA = gpa; this->next = next;
}
```

)
    StudentInfo *s1 = new StudentInfo {"phi", "123", "computer science", 4.0, nullptr};
    StudentInfo *s2 = new StudentInfo {"abc", "123", "software engineer", 4.0, nullptr };
    StudentInfo *s3 = new StudentInfo {"zxc", "123", "business management", 4.0, nullptr };

and then

```
list.push(s1);
list.push(s2);
list.push(s3);
```

Comment: what parameter type should I use for `nullptr`?

Comment: @PhiTruong What parameter are you saying? Its class definition is an aggregate.

Comment: @PhiTruong Either remove the constructor because it is redundant due to the fact that all data members are public or make the fifth parameter with the default argument that corresponds to the data member next.

Comment: Thank, I didn't know, I can start an object in C++ without an constructor.